# Multiprocessing: Hiding DB connection to fork processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pool, dbconnection

Trying to fork processes from inside a method, but i'm getting the following error :

```
 TypeError: can't pickle psycopg2.extensions.connection objects
```

when I instantiate a method :

```
res = pool.map(self.abc, data)
```

and yes I have a db connection stored in self.db. I have no problem if I instantiate simple function

```
res = pool.map(abc, data)
```

The problem is I cant extract the logic outside the Class, there are too many dependencies.

My question is : Is there a way to "MASK" temporarily self.db, so I can lunch the "pool" and "UNMASK" it afterwards, so that pool.map() doesnt try to pickle the db connection

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work via global variable and function.. its ugly but ...

```
 global SELF
 def REDIRECT(arg) : return SELF.method(arg)

 class ....:

   def blah(self):
    ...
    global SELF
    SELF = self

    with Pool(....) as pool :

       res = pool.map(REDIRECT, data)
```